# Grails/GORM: What is the correct/best way to map these two domains?

Tags: grails, grails-orm

I have a User domain class, and a List one.

Each list must have an author (a user) and each user must have a "primary list". Only some of the lists will have the "primaryList" statute.

So.. somthing like

```
 User:
    List primaryList

 List:
    User author

    static belongsTo = User
```

Of course this does not work as intended because the two relations are mistakenly taken as only one. I should also add a hasMany on the User and other belongsTo to the List..., but I don't want to complicate the example because I want to get the right answer from you.

Comment: @Long a list belongs only to a user.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may need to use [mappedBy](http://grails.org/doc/latest/ref/Domain%20Classes/mappedBy.html) to explain how the fields in User and List line up. Here are a couple domains that I wrote that allow a User to author many Lists but only set one to be "primary". There are a couple extra nullable constraints so you can use the scaffolded UI without getting into a chicken-and-egg scenario.

```
class User {
    String name
    FooList primaryList

    static hasMany = [authoredLists: FooList]

    static mappedBy = [primaryList: 'primaryOwner', authoredLists: 'author']

    static constraints = {
        primaryList nullable: true, unique: true
        authoredLists nullable: true
    }

    String toString() { name }
}
```

I named this class "FooList" just to avoid confusion with the standard List class:

```
class FooList {
    static belongsTo = [author: User, primaryOwner: User]

    static constraints = {
        primaryOwner nullable: true, display: false
    }
}
```

Comment: Can't I have on FooList just one user reference - the "author"? Because a list cannot have an author and be a primary list to other user. And then I need just a one-directional mark from User to know which list is it's primary list (it can be in authoredLists or not)... Because of time constraints I resolved this by putting in user a Integer primaryListId instead of a FooList field... but I want to refactor it because it's ugly.

Answer (score 2):

Try using the map belongsTo approach:

```
static belongsTo = [user:User]
```

That way Grails should see the 2 properties as separate.

Comment: tried this, actually my working example is more complicated, but I would like to see how others would do this.